# JSON string to rails hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, json, parsing, hash

I'm on Rails 2.3 and I'm trying to convert a string that is JSON-formatted to a Rails hash. However, when I use `JSON.parse` I get a JSON string without the delimiters:

```
{"source_id":40007,"object":"86088947610496.1","coursewalk_id":"86088947610477.1","description":"","image_uri":"db\/db-files\/
Image_2011-09-24_14.37.37__0000.jpg","latitude":"38.0113439821061","letter":"","letter_A":"","letter_B":"","letter_C":"","lett
er_D":"","letter_E":"","letter_F":"","longitude":"-78.7576854509104","number":"1","mcw_id":71}
```

Results of `JSON.parse`:

```
number1letter_Bcoursewalk_id86088947610477.1letter_Clatitude38.0113439821061letter_Dletter_Eletter_Fmcw_id71longitude-78.75768
54509104letterdescriptionobject86088947610496.1source_id40007letter_Aimage_uridb/db-files/Image_2011-09-24_14.37.37__0000.jpg
```

Code:

```
puts string_to_parse
fence_parsed = JSON.parse(string_to_parse)
puts fence_parsed
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Could you check class of fence_parsed variable? "puts fence_parsed.class"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just because you're using "puts". If you just type `fence_parsed`, or `p fence_parsed` you'll get what you're looking for. `puts` calls `to_s`. I hope this clears it up for you, if not let me know and I'll elaborate.

Comment: That's what it was! Can't believe how many hours I wasted. Thanks!